# Summing values based on values in other column (Variable)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, window-functions

I would like to sum all items within the query based on their **ITEM**, keep in mind this query is a daily report that will pick up different **ITEM**'s depending on which items were purchased that day. Therefore, a basic CASE wont work.

For example:

ITEM_TABLE: expected result

```
Item Type       Amount        SUM
----------------------------------
SCARF           10            10
T-Shirt         20            45
T-Shirt         25            45
```

Current Query:

```
select SUM(AMOUNT) 
from EDSREP.V_COGNOS_WSSTOR_SETTLE_RECON a 
having CCY_CODE = a.CCY_CODE
```

Nothing is showing up, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select
    item_type,
    amount,
    sum(amount) over(partition by item_type) sum_amount
from item_table
```